# Mysql Fiterby Multiple Checkboxes the Right Way

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox, filter

I want to Filter from  **MyTable**

the way I get as result only the rows corresponding to the checkboxes checked.

```
(1) <input type="cBox" name="Filter[Table_Column_Name_X]" value="y" />
(2) <input type="cBox" name="Filter[Table_Column_Name_Y]" value="y" />
(3) <input type="cBox" name="Filter[Table_Column_Name_Z]" value="y" />
```

**Ex.:**

***if 'only' checkbox (1) is checked***

I retrieve *'only'* the rows  `WHERE Table_Column_Name_X='y'`

***if checkbox (1) and if checkbox (3) are checked***

I retrieve *'only'* the rows  `WHERE Table_Column_Name_X='y' AND Table_Column_Name_Z='y'`

***.........and so on foreach checkbox checked!***

Something like this

```
if(isset($_POST['Filter'][]) && !empty($_POST['Filter'][]){
$query= "Select * From MyTable WHERE  Table_Columns_Names_Checked='y'";
}
```

Myabe I should use variables or foreach statement. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML code is incorrect:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Filter[]" value="Table_Column_Name_X" />
<input type="checkbox" name="Filter[]" value="Table_Column_Name_Y" />
<input type="checkbox" name="Filter[]" value="Table_Column_Name_Z" />
```

Your PHP code (following code is untested):

```
$where = "";
if(isset($_POST['Filter'] ) {
  foreach( $_POST['Filter'] as $filter ) {
    switch( $filter ) {
      case 'Table_Column_Name_X' : if( $where != '' ) $where .= " AND ";
                                   $where .= Table_Column_Name_X = ??????????;
                                   break;
      //--- repeat above for other 2 options
  }
  $sql = "Select * From MyTable";
  if( $where != "" ) $sql .= " WHERE " . $where;
  //--- do the query
```

The ????? indicates that the column must have a particular value for the query to work on otherwise it will just return everything and there is no need for the filter.

It is not wise to use table/fieldnames in your HTML as you are exposing the structure of you database to would be hackers. Use numbers instead.

Comment: I will test yr code by tomorrow and I will leave u a feedback. thank u for advising about security that was nice of you.

Comment: `$where = "";`
`if(isset($_POST['Filter']) && !empty($_POST['Filter'])){`
`foreach( $_POST['Filter'] as $filter ) {`
switch( $filter ) {
case 'Elevator' : if( $where != '' ) $where .= " AND ";
$where .= 'y';
break;`

Comment: Now I miss the most important part "Do your query". What should I put with your code as query?

Comment: You modifications will not work. Your sql statement will end up looking like  'SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE y,y'. From my code, replace Table_Column_Name_X=?????? to Elevator='y' and make the necessary adjustments to the other 2 entries. The 'do the query' is the statement that actually calls the database to get the data.